# set encoding of rails 3 form to fix IE bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

On my app i noticed that IE8 will not post my form when trying to upload a photo. The form upload works in every other browser.

I researched and found that i might end to set the encoding as well as the enctype to "multipart/form-data". Ive set the enctype but how do I set the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Rails Guide [Uploading Files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)

As they suggest in the guide
your answer is the set `:multipart => true`.

Notably Rails 3.1 now does this automatically for you, but I'd be inclined to make it explicit.

eg.

```
<%= form_for @person, :multipart => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
<% end %>
```